# Can a number have two decimal points like 274..2 in maths or any physics notation.

Tags: notation

There is book of physics and it's written in it that the gravitational acceleration on the surface of the sun is 274..2 I wanted to know if it's a printing mistake or it's some kind of a notation in physics or maths.

Comment: Almost surely a printing mistake.

Comment: I've never seen that notation in a mathematical text.  Perhaps if you gave the title and author (edition, publisher, year, etc.), Readers would be better able to help you.

Comment: The gravitational acceleration on the surface of the sun is in fact $274.2\ \mathrm{ms}^{-2}$, so it's just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in the comments, this is a typo; there is no widely used notation for the decimal representation of numbers that uses two consecutive decimal points.